# issue with starting java web start application on linux

Tags: java, linux, java-web-start

Operating System: Linux version 2.6.18-308.1.1.el5 (mockbuild@x86-002.build.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)) #1 SMP Fri Feb 17 16:47:13 EST 2012

```
Java Version: Match: digest selected JREDesc: JREDesc[version 1.6+, heap=134217728-536870912, args=-ea, href=null, sel=false, null, null], JREInfo: JREInfo for index 0:
    platform is: 1.7
    product is: 1.7.0_17
    location is: http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se
    path is: /usr/java/jre1.7.0_17/bin/java
```

Tried with Mozilla Firefox.

Problem: Unable to start the java web start application for JRE 1.7.0, even though I am using the deployment toolkit.

- source for html for JRE 7.0: deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton(url,'1.7.0');
- source for html for JRE 6.0: deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton(url,'1.6.0');

Note:
The application runs perfectly fine in a Windows environment, and Linux is running the 1.6 version just fine. I also noticed the default JRE of the machine is still 1.6.0, even though I have installed JRE 1.7.0 using RPM from [here](http://java.com/en/download/linux_manual.jsp?host=java.com) and when I am trying to install now it is saying that the JRE is already installed.

Update: I have updated the default JRE, now it shows JRE 1.7.0

```
[root@L3FMV80 defaults]# java -version
java version "1.7.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

[root@L3FMV80 Downloads]# rpm -ivh jre-7u17-linux-i586.rpm 
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
        package jre-1.7.0_17-fcs.i586 is already installed
```

Comment: `sudo /usr/sbin/alternatives --config java` … or is it `update-alternatives`? I can't remember

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what distribution you are using. Try installing openjdk icedtea-web, the latter being a web start implementation and a browser plug-in.

You don't have to be using the browser plug-in. You can open the file with the "javaws" program.

Comment: I don't understand "what distribution you are using". I have specified all the details about operating system and java version and I can not let my client to run program using javaws.

Comment: @Ashish, too bad you not trying to answer what you are asked and hurry with -1. I don't feel like motivated to help you. FYI kernel version is not everything, firefox does not mean much without a version. Different distros have different libraries so sometimes same version of program/kernel/java behave differently. You not telling anything about what you're seeing in your browser trying to open app. Good luck..

Answer (score -1):

I have good solution from [this](http://yuenhoe.com/blog/2010/03/working-with-java-web-start-jnlp-in-firefoxopensuse-and-linux-in-general/)

> So after a good long time not being able to play this Facebook game
>   we’re building for P2P-related research, which runs on Java Web Start,
>   I finally got pissed today and sat down and finally got to the bottom
>   of it.
>
> Because Java isn’t free technology and all that, OpenSUSE actually
>   comes preinstalled with OpenJDK instead of the common version of Java
>   distributed by Sun. With this default configuration, Web Start (JNLP)
>   files on the internet will open by default in an open implementation
>   of Java Web Start called ‘IcedTea Web Start’, which I hear works
>   reasonably well – but outright doesn’t work for some cases, like mine.
>
> For people who, like me, need to run Sun’s version of Web Start from
>   Firefox – first, you need to grab and install Sun’s version of the
>   Java runtime using your software package manager (in OpenSUSE the
>   package is called java-1_6_0-sun). Verify that you have a program
>   called ‘javaws’ after this step. You can simply type ‘javaws’ into an
>   open terminal and make sure it is recognized as Java(TM) Web Start.
>
> Okay, next all we need to do is get Firefox to use javaws when opening
>   **JNLP files.** For other distros you’d go to **Edit > Preferences >**
>   Applications in Firefox, look for JNLP, and change the setting so it
>   uses javaws. On OpenSUSE, Firefox is integrated so it takes its
>   file-association settings directly from KDE. So you’ll have to instead
>   go to KDE’s systemsettings (Configure Desktop) > Advanced Tab > File
>   Associations. Here, run a search for JNLP, then add ‘/usr/bin/javaws’
>   to the top of the Application Preference Order.
>
> We’re done! Next time you open a JNLP Web Start file in Firefox, it
>   should offer to use Sun’s Java Web Start to open it :)

Useful Link: [how to run jnlp files under ubuntu](http://yuenhoe.com/blog/2010/03/working-with-java-web-start-jnlp-in-firefoxopensuse-and-linux-in-general/)